# Flutter. Grouped list by a field which is a list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, slug, grouped-list

I have a list of items with field groups. Groups is also list. I want to display this list of that items grouped by groups. The item can be the part of two or more group.

```
List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
        id: '1',
        title: 'Apple and more more thing', description: 'Some data to describe',
        group: ['Picnic', 'New'], price: 25, bonus: 1, quantity: 1.5, measure: 'кг', measureStep: 1.5,
        imageUrl: 'assets/fruits/orange.jpg'),
    Product(
        id: '2',
        title: 'Apple and more more thing', description: 'Some data to describe',
        price: 24.50, bonus: 1, group: ['Picnic', 'New'], quantity: 1.5, measure: 'кг', measureStep: 1.5,
        imageUrl: 'assets/fruits/orange.jpg'),
    Product(
        id: '3',
        title: 'Apple and more more thing', description: 'Some data to describe',
        price: 5.00, bonus: 1, group: ['New'], quantity: 1, measure: 'шт', measureStep: 1,
        imageUrl: 'assets/fruits/orange.jpg'),
    Product(
        id: '4',
        title: 'Apple and more more thing', description: 'Some data to describe',
        price: 24.00, bonus: 1, group: ['New'], quantity: 1.250, measure: 'кг', measureStep: 1.250,
        imageUrl: 'assets/fruits/orange.jpg'),
    Product(
        id: '5',
        title: 'Apple and more more thing', description: 'Some data to describe',
        price: 15.75, bonus: 1, group: ['Picnic'], quantity: 1, measure: 'шт', measureStep: 1,
        imageUrl: 'assets/fruits/orange.jpg'),
    Product(
        id: '6',
        title: 'Apple and more more thing', description: 'Some data to describe',
        price: 9.50, bonus: 1, group: ['For children', 'New'], quantity: 0.5, measure: 'лт', measureStep: 0.5,
        imageUrl: 'assets/fruits/orange.jpg'),
    Product(
        id: '7',
        title: 'Apple and more more thing', description: 'Some data to describe',
        price: 40.00, bonus: 1, group: ['For children'], quantity: 1, measure: 'шт', measureStep: 1,
        imageUrl: 'assets/fruits/orange.jpg'),
    Product(
        id: '8',
        title: 'Apple and more more thing', description: 'Some data to describe',
        price: 32.50, bonus: 1, group: ['For children', 'New'], quantity: 1.75, measure: 'кг', measureStep: 1.75,
        imageUrl: 'assets/fruits/orange.jpg')
```

I am new in flutter, so can you give some idea how it is possible or code will be perfect.

[image: I made grouped list by one string, but now I have there a list.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```dart
  var list = [
    Product(id: '1', groups: ['Picnic', 'New']),
    Product(id: '2', groups: ['For children', 'New']),
    Product(id: '3', groups: ['New']),
    Product(id: '4', groups: ['For children']),
  ];

  var groupedLists = {};

  list.forEach((product) {
    product.groups.forEach((group) {
      if (groupedLists['$group'] == null) {
        groupedLists['$group'] = <Product>[];
      }

      (groupedLists['$group'] as List<Product>).add(product);
    });
  });

  print(groupedLists);
```

the result is:

```
{
Picnic: [Instance of 'Product'], 
New: [Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product'], 
For children: [Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product']
}
```

Now you can easily display them in `LisView`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Group
var listGroup = {};

_listLayer.forEach((eleParent) {

  var filter =
      _listLayer.where((eleChild) => eleChild.group == eleParent.group).toList();//Filter

  listGroup[eleParent.group] = filter;//Add
});
```

==> After group

[image]